ERROR resolving with preferred channel: Post "https://api.charmhub.io/v2/charms/refresh": EOF
I am installing ubuntu 20.04，and juju deploy cmd works fine last Friday
but today(Monday) I remove-app/unit/machime then deploy again, when I run the cmd just the same as last Friday,it get errors:
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ juju deploy --to 8 --config /home/openstack-base-yoga-79/nova-compute/nova-compute-enp129s0f0-48core.yaml nova-compute nova-compute-enp129s0f0-48core --debug
16:07:33 INFO  juju.cmd supercommand.go:56 running juju [2.9.50 171c5b64e8651a45efeb2e60c0a18ea372a31d21 gc go1.21.12]
16:07:33 DEBUG juju.cmd supercommand.go:57   args: []string{"/snap/juju/28040/bin/juju", "deploy", "--to", "8", "--config", "/home/openstack-base-yoga-79/nova-compute/nova-compute-enp129s0f0-48core.yaml", "nova-compute", "nova-compute-enp129s0f0-48core", "--debug"}
16:07:33 INFO  juju.juju api.go:86 connecting to API addresses: [156.28.11.15:17070]
16:07:33 DEBUG juju.api apiclient.go:1151 successfully dialed "wss://156.28.11.15:17070/api"
16:07:33 INFO  juju.api apiclient.go:686 connection established to "wss://156.28.11.15:17070/api"
16:07:33 INFO  juju.juju api.go:86 connecting to API addresses: [156.28.11.15:17070]
16:07:33 DEBUG juju.api apiclient.go:1151 successfully dialed "wss://156.28.11.15:17070/model/1dc85570-8972-45ac-876f-9fba407527c6/api"
16:07:33 INFO  juju.api apiclient.go:686 connection established to "wss://156.28.11.15:17070/model/1dc85570-8972-45ac-876f-9fba407527c6/api"
16:07:34 DEBUG juju.cmd.juju.application.deployer deployer.go:396 cannot interpret as local charm: file does not exist
16:07:34 DEBUG juju.cmd.juju.application.deployer deployer.go:208 cannot interpret as a redeployment of a local charm from the controller
16:07:34 DEBUG juju.api monitor.go:35 RPC connection died
16:07:34 DEBUG juju.api monitor.go:35 RPC connection died
ERROR resolving with preferred channel: Post "https://api.charmhub.io/v2/charms/refresh": EOF
16:07:34 DEBUG cmd supercommand.go:537 error stack:
resolving with preferred channel: Post "https://api.charmhub.io/v2/charms/refresh": EOF
github.com/juju/juju/cmd/juju/application/store.(*CharmAdaptor).ResolveCharm:100:
github.com/juju/juju/cmd/juju/application/store.(*CharmAdaptor).ResolveBundleURL:135:
github.com/juju/juju/cmd/juju/application/deployer.(*factory).maybeReadRepositoryBundle:464:
github.com/juju/juju/cmd/juju/application/deployer.(*factory).GetDeployer:71:
github.com/juju/juju/cmd/juju/application.(*DeployCommand).Run:909:

I am sure that maas and controller Node can conntect with the internet, maybe something wrong with CharmHub? I am not sure but it seems no errors from my side
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ wget www.google.com
--2024-09-09 16:02:22--  http://www.google.com/
Connecting to 192.2.200.102:8080... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html.7’

index.html.7                                          [ <=>                                                                                                          ]  21.21K  --.-KB/s    in 0.04s

2024-09-09 16:02:22 (498 KB/s) - ‘index.html.7’ saved [21717]

ubuntu@controller:~$ wget www.google.com
--2024-09-09 08:01:52--  http://www.google.com/
Connecting to 192.2.200.102:8080... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html.1’

index.html.1                                          [ <=>                                                                                                          ]  21.15K  --.-KB/s    in 0.04s

2024-09-09 08:01:52 (577 KB/s) - ‘index.html.1’ saved [21662]

